# Perform conversions on all datetimes on get/set?

Tags: c#, datetime, entity-framework-6

I have a database first ASP.NET MVC (C#) project with EF6, which uses a lot of DateTime objects.

They are stored in the database as my local Time-Zone(TZ), however some users are in different TZs (also stored in the database) and I would like to present them with DateTimes for their own TZ.

I have set up some functions accessible from all relevant controllers to do the conversions, but I'm hoping there is a quicker way to apply them in all cases than finding and explicitly converting each instance of each DateTime where needed to display on every view and converting them back again after form POSTs.

On loading a view, the TZ needs to be converted to the User's TZ.

On saving a form, any DateTimes in the form need to be converted back again.

The functions which perform the conversions first check whether it is required according to the User's recorded TZ.

Is there some way I can put all DateTime objects through the conversion when getting and setting them, or something along those lines?

Comment: NB: do not store date/time with time zone. Convert it to UTC before saving to database, store without time zone information, and convert to the user time zone before displaying it in UI.

Comment: I did not design the database and it has a lot of historical data. The datetime entries do not have tz info, but observation of the old application using the database showed me that they are my own timezone. If I had designed the database it would store in UTC. This is why I explicitly mentioned that it is database first.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on how you access your database. Let's take the **Entity Framework example**

There, you have the [Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading from or writing to the database. This conversion can be from one value to another of the same type (for example, encrypting strings) or from a value of one type to a value of another type (for example, converting enum values to and from strings in the database.)

So in this example, you would create your own DBContext with the `TZ` in the constructor and pass it to the converter

```
var converter = new LocalToTZConverter<DateTime>(timezone);

modelBuilder
    .Entity<DateEnabled>()
    .Property(e => e.Created)
    .HasConversion(converter);
```

Assuming that you use some kind of ORM, pretty much everyone has it's own conversion. If this is something you implement yourself, then you'd handle it in your repositories and have it as a coding practice to never access data directly (only though the repos).

Comment: Thanks @athanasios-kataras I am using Entity Framework, so I'll have a look at this option and see how I go :)

Comment: I'm using EF 6 but unfortunately this seems to be only available using EF Core. Not sure if I'll be able to use this method at this stage!

Comment: You are quite right https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/710 and the team is not going to implement it.